# Выход из метода из оператора присвоения

Tags: c#

InputString может возвращать null.
Как сделать так чтобы в этом случае происходил выход из метода?

```
public void Functionality()
        {
            Print.PrintLogo("AddEmployee");
            string FirstName = Print.InputString("Введите имя нового сотрудника: ");
            string LastName = Print.InputString("Введите фамилию нового сотрудника: ");
            string PhoneNumber = Print.InputString("Введите номер телефона нового сотрудника: ");
            string Description = Print.InputString("Введите описание нового сотрудника: ");
            var tempEmp = new Employee(FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, Description);
            if (_employees == null || _employees.Count == 0)
                _employees = new List<Employee>() { tempEmp };
            else
                _employees.Add(tempEmp);
            JsonController.PushEmpToJson(_employees);
        }
```

Comment: `if (x == null) { return; }`

Answer (score 2):

Делайте проверку на `null` и в случае `true` выходите из метода с помощью `return`

```
string? FirstName = Print.InputString("Введите имя нового сотрудника: ");
if (FirstName is null) return;

string? LastName = Print.InputString("Введите фамилию нового сотрудника: ");
if (LastName is null) return;

string? PhoneNumber = Print.InputString("Введите номер телефона нового сотрудника: ");
if (PhoneNumber is null) return;

string? Description = Print.InputString("Введите описание нового сотрудника: ")
if (Description is null) return;
```

Answer (score 1):

Не программирую на C#, но обычно делается так:

```
        public void Functionality()
        {
            Print.PrintLogo("AddEmployee");
            string FirstName = Print.InputString("Введите имя нового сотрудника: ");
            string LastName = Print.InputString("Введите фамилию нового сотрудника: ");
            string PhoneNumber = Print.InputString("Введите номер телефона нового сотрудника: ");
            string Description = Print.InputString("Введите описание нового сотрудника: ");

            // Проверяем выводы InputString на null
            if (FirstName == null || LastName == null || PhoneNumber == null || Description == null)
                return;

            var tempEmp = new Employee(FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, Description);

            if (_employees == null || _employees.Count == 0)
                _employees = new List<Employee>() { tempEmp };
            else
                _employees.Add(tempEmp);
            JsonController.PushEmpToJson(_employees);
        }
```

Comment: Не вариант, надо чтобы проверка в каждой строчке была

Comment: @Tarant1no что вам мешает проверять по отдельности сразу после ввода?

Comment: В `4 строке` вы попытались воспользоваться оператором `??` `null-объединения`, но он служит для установки значений по умолчанию, поэтому нельзя использовать `return`.

Comment: @Vipz это - опечатка, поправил.